# AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributes, odoo

Kindly  correct the code as I'm getting attribute error at this point of time

XML is given below:

```
<field name="rate" on_change="on_change_ded_cal(rate)"/>
<field name="ded"/>
```

.Py file is given  below

```
def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids, rate, context=None):
    x=rate+2
    return {'value': {'ded': x}}
```

Complete Error Message is given below

```
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-       231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1128, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
**AttributeError: 'test_base' object has no attribute 'on_change_ded_cal'**
```

Also complete .py file is given below for further reference

```
from osv import osv

from osv import fields

class test_base(osv.osv):
    _name='test.base'
    _columns={
        'name':fields.char('Name'),
        'email':fields.char('Email'),

        'code':fields.integer('Unique ID'),
        'sal':fields.float('Salary'),
        'rate':fields.selection((('10','10%'), ('20','20%'),('30','30%')),
               'Percentage of Deduction'),
        'ded':fields.float('Deduction'),

         }

test_base()

def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids, rate, context=None):
    x=rate+2
    return {'value': {'ded': x}}
```

Comment: no attribute error there, because you don't access any attributes

Comment: What is the full error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry for that....I have provided error message above

Comment: @user3153567 You should put `on_change_ded_cal` method inside the class body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class test_base(osv.osv):    
    _name='test.base'
    _columns={
        'name':fields.char('Name'),
        'email':fields.char('Email'),
        'code':fields.integer('Unique ID'),
        'sal':fields.float('Salary'),
        'rate':fields.selection((('10','10%'), ('20','20%'),('30','30%')),
               'Percentage of Deduction'),
        'ded':fields.float('Deduction'),
         }

    def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids, rate, context=None):
        x=rate+2
        return {'value': {'ded': x}} 

test_base()
```

Comment: hello, you write on_change method out side the class. so it getting error. Define your all method inside the class.

Comment: Hi , First of all i would like to thank you all for your valuable time.  Again I executed after placing  on_change_method inside the class and little indentation and data type changes.. It worked !!!